# How to get a permission mask in Sharepoint 2007?

Tags: sharepoint, mask, permissions

How to get a permission mask in Sharepoint 2007?

Answer (score 1):

SPWeb web_current = SPControl.GetContextWeb(Context);

Int64 decValue = (Int64) web_current.EffectiveBasePermissions;

return decValue.ToString("X");